# Windows - Get proccess running from file

Tags: windows, security, windows-explorer, process

What I have is a process running on a port and I want to know what process is running on that port, but from files, not commands.

With a command, in cmd, in would be something like this:

`FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5 delims= " %i IN (netstat -ano ^|find "8080") DO @tasklist /fi "pid eq %i" | find "%i`

And after obtaining the process, lets say it's java.java, further information could be retrieved with:

```
WMIC path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline | findstr "java"
```

I want to achieve it just by information inside files, this requirement of information inside files is because I have a path traversal and a probably vulnerable service running on a port, and I want to know which service is running (nmap can't do this task) I have to know which service is running by analyzing files.

Thank you very much

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. It's Windows not Linux and the example you give IS using a command (netstat) not the contents of a file.

Comment: You haven't read the entire post I guess I said how to achieve it with a command, and I want the same result just by exploring files. Thank  you for your -1, that was pretty nasty

Comment: You can't. This isn't Linux. It's Windows.

Comment: How can you be so sure¿? Don't affirm that so categorically if you are not 100% sure, that's a big statement to say that you just can't, I think there could be ways...

Comment: I'm 100%, unequivocally sure you cannot do this. You are trying to compare Windows to Linux where every component of the operating system is accessible via file stream. Windows gives us all the commands and APIs do this. The data is not stored somewhere in a "file."

Comment: Well maybe you are right but I think I didn't say the registry also counts. It can be achieved also using the registry. For example, via this file:  `c:\windows\system32\config\software.sav` I have been able to list many applications, and paths, but still not open ports and processes running on these ports. Thanks

Comment: Please explain why the operational requirement for constraining answers to *just by information inside files.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This isn't possible.

> I want to know what process is running on that port, but from files, not commands.

There are no files in Windows that contain this information. Not even the Registry (which is a file-based database) stores this information.

As an aside, if this information were stored in a file, I find it curious how you would *access* it without executing something (a.k.a. a "command"). After all, commands are how we tell Windows what information we want to access.